# ¿se pueden poner aqui los requires?(en un plugin de wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin

estoy haciendo un plugin de wordpress y no me muestra el "hola mundo" que deberia. En cambio si comento los requires si me lo muestra. ¿estoy situando bien los requires para este plugin?¿se pueden poner dentro de la funcion `add_shortcode`?

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Luilli Cl@ve
 * Plugin URI: https://pablomonteserin.com
 * Description: Inserta un banner de publicidad con el shortcode banner
 * Version: 1.0.0
 * Author: Luilli
 * Author URI: https://pablomonteserin.com
 * License: GPL2
 */

 
add_shortcode( "luilliclave", function($atts, $content){

require_once WP_PLUGIN_DIR.'/luilliclave/lib/SAML2/Constants.php';
require_once WP_PLUGIN_DIR.'/luilliclave/lib/SimpleSAML/Auth/Simple.php';
require_once WP_PLUGIN_DIR.'/luilliclave/lib/SimpleSAML/Auth/Source.php';
require_once WP_PLUGIN_DIR.'/luilliclave/lib/SimpleSAML/Configuration.php';

$authSource = SAML2\Constants::SPID;
$assertion_url= SAML2\Constants::ASSERTION_URL;

$as = new SimpleSAML_Auth_Simple($authSource);
$as = SimpleSAML_Auth_Source::getById($authSource);

$localConfig = $as->getLocalConfig();
$idp = $as->getLocalConfig()->getString("idp", NULL);

    $output = '<html> hola mundo </html>';
    return $output;
});
```

El plugin es para integrar la autentificacion con cl@ve en wordpress.  La aplicacion en php funciona correctamente segun la he descargado de la pagina del ministerio, pero estoy intentando integrarla en un plugin de wordpress. De momento como estoy empezando y no tengo conocimientos avanzados de plugins en wordpress solo pretendo que se muestre correctamente el "hola mundo" despues de haber requerido los archivos que serian necesarios para hacer funcionar el programa.

Comment: Haz un `echo WP_PLUGIN_DIR.'/luilliclave/lib/SAML2/Constants.php';` y verifica si se produce la ruta correcta. Si es la ruta correcta verifica que los nombres de archivo están todos bien.

Comment: intenta cambiarlo por esto
require_once( WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/luilliclave/lib/SAML2/Constants.php' );
Siempre verifica que la ruta sea la correcta

Comment: lo he intentado con la solucion de jefferzon, y el resultado es el mismo: instala y se activa pero no muestra el "hola mundo" por pantalla. Las rutas deben estar bien ya que si pongo una que no exista me da un error y no se me activa el plugin. Sigo teniendo la misma duda de si los requires estan bien dentro de la funcion add_shortcode.

Comment: si pongo los requires fuera de la funcion `add_shortcode` me lanza este error al activarlo:`Fatal error: Cannot declare class SimpleSAML_Module, because the name is already in use in /home/u117490907/domains/coronavirusilladearousa.es/public_html/wp-content/plugins/luilliclave/lib/SimpleSAML/Module.php on line 11`. Y no entiendo por que ya que la aplicacion php funciona perfectamente.

Comment: En vez de `require_once` usa `include_once`.

Comment: con include_once me da el mismo error. El problema es que no me dice donde esta declarado `SimpleSAML_Module`. Me dice que no se puede declarar porque ya esta declarada en Module.php. Pero no me dice en donde es que no se puede declarar.